# C++ boost - Is there a container working like a queue with direct key access?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers

I was wonndering about a queue-like container but which has key-access, like a map.
My goal is simple : I want a FIFO queue, but, if I insert an element and an element with a given key is already in the queue, I want it the new element to **replaced** the one already in the queue. For example, a map ordered by insertion time would work .

If there is no container like that, do you think it can be implemented by using both a queue and a map ?

Comment: Actually using a list with remove_if does the trick ! Now perf wise, a list+map might be better, but that's not even sure, provided you have to update the map everytime the list changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Boost multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) provides this kind of container.

To implement it myself, I'd probably go for a `map` whose values consist of a linked list node plus a payload. The list node could be hand-rolled, or could be [Boost intrusive](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/intrusive.html).

Note that the main point of the `queue` adaptor is to hide most of the interface of Sequence, but you want to mess with the details it hides. So I think you should aim to reproduce the interface of `queue` (slightly modified with your altered semantics for `push`) rather than actually use it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously what you want can be done simply with the queue-like container, but you would have to spend `O(n)` time on every insertion to determine if the element is already present. If you implement your queue based on something like `std::vector` you could use the binary search and basically speed up your insertion to `O(log n)` *(that would still require `O(n)` operations when the memory reallocation is done).*

**If this is fine, just stick to it.** The variant with additional container might give you a performance boost, but it's also likely to be error-prone to write and if the first solution is sufficient, just use it.

---

In the second scenario you might want to store your elements twice in different containers - the original queue and something like a map (or sometimes a *hashmap* may perform better). The map is used only to determine if the element is already present in the container or not - and if YES, you will have to update it in your queue.

Basically that gives us `O(1)` complexity for hashmap lookups *(in real world this might get uglier because of the collisions - hashmaps aren't really good for determining element existence)* and `O(1)` insertion time for the case when no update is required and `O(n)` insertion time for the case update is needed.

Based on the percentage of the actual update operations, the actual insertion performance may vary from `O(1)` to `O(n)`, but this scheme will definitely outperform the first one if the number of updates is small enough.

*Still, you have to insert your elements in two containers simultaneosly and the same should be done if the element is deleted and I would think twice "do I really need that performance boost?".*

Answer (score 0):

I see easy way of doing this with a queue and optionally a map.

Define some sort of == operator for your elements.

Then simply have a queue and search for your element every time you want to insert it.

You could optimize this by having a map of element locations to elements instead of searching the queue every time.